# How to configure 2.6 spring: Failed to create route route2 at:

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm trying to upgrade from Camel 2.0 to 2.6

I have this in my applicationContext-camel.xml file...

```
<camel:route >
<camel:from uri="transactionSaleBuffer" />
<camel:policy ref="routeTransactionPolicy"/>
<camel:transacted ref="transactionManagerETL" />
<camel:to uri="detailFactProcessor" />
</camel:route>
```

by adding in the two lines in the middle (policy and transacted) I get the exception...

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route2 at: >>> From[transactionSaleBuffer] <<< in route: Route[[From[transactionSaleBuffer]] -> [Tr
>   ansacted[ref:trans... because of Route route2 has no output processors. You need to add outputs to the route such as to("log:foo").

I can see this is because the Camel class RouteDefinition.java makes a call to ProcessorDefinitionHelper.hasOutputs(outputs, true).

This passes in an array of one Object ([Transacted[ref:transactionManagerETL]])

This one object has one two children

```
[Transacted[ref:transactionManagerETL]]
CHILD-[Policy[ref:routeTransactionPolicy], 
CHILD-To[detailFactProcessor]
```

The Policy child has no outputs, so the exception is thrown.

Yet I don't know how to add a child, my XML above matches the schema.

Maybe I'm missing something else?

My setup matches the example...[Apache Camel: Book in One Page](http://Camel%201.x%20-%20JMS%20Sample) (See section: Camel 1.x - JMS Sample)

Can anyone please help me out.
Thanks!
Jeff Porter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows

```
<camel:route>
  <camel:from uri="transactionSaleBuffer" />
  <camel:transacted ref="transactionManagerETL" />
  <camel:policy ref="routeTransactionPolicy">
    <camel:to uri="detailFactProcessor" />
  </camel:policy>
</camel:route>
```

Comment: awesome. I must of been having a senior moment. I had the policy defined that used the transaction (transactionManagerETL), then I also had the transaction as a child of the route. Thanks for the advice!